# Change item during ItemAdding [not an error]

Tags: event-receivers

I'm trying to update `SiteUrl` field during ItemAdding event. The field is `Type="URL"`. I use this code in Event Receiver, but after user added new item, the field is still empty. (User cannot set this field himself. It has `ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE"`).

```
    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPFieldUrlValue urlValue = new SPFieldUrlValue();
        urlValue.Description = "site description...";
        urlValue.Url = properties.Web.Url;
        properties.AfterProperties["SiteUrl"] = urlValue;

    }
```

Is there some method to save properties, or am I missing something obvious here?

EDIT: turned out, this code is correct, only field name had typo. I found it out only after adding try-catch and debugging inside code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your code code in try-catch block or debug your solution from visual studio. I suppose "SiteUrl" field is not in AfterProperties collection because it is not changing by user.

You do not filter values or cancel item adding, so maybe ItemAdded event is a possible way out? It's much easier to use it.

Comment: I agree with doing this in ItemAdded, directly on the item instead of on the AfterProperties, seems like a better solution!

Comment: Yes, turned out, that code was correct, only field name had typo. I found it out only after adding try-catch and debugging inside code.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.EventFiringEnabled = false;

    SPFieldUrlValue urlValue = new SPFieldUrlValue();
    urlValue.Description = "site description...";
    urlValue.Url = properties.Web.Url;
    properties.AfterProperties["SiteUrl"] = urlValue;
    properties.Listitem.update();

    base.EventFiringEnabled = true;

}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverbase.eventfiringenabled.aspx

in item added the code will look somthing like this:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{

SPListItem listLink = properties.Listitem;

SPFieldUrlValue value = new SPFieldUrlValue();

value.Description = "test";

value.Url = "http://www.microsoft.com/sharepoint";

listLink["URL"] = value;

listLink.Update();

}
```

Comment: Would not properties.listItem be null in itemadding, since the item is not yet created. Or am I just Friday tired ;)

Comment: I think its Friday tired ;) its in added not adding :)

Comment: But, the almost last line in adding is surely a listItem.update(), even this Saturday ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
            {
                try
                {

                    SPFieldUrlValue urlValue = new SPFieldUrlValue();
                    urlValue.Description = "Description will appear in the ink";
                    urlValue.Url = properties.RelativeWebUrl + "/_layouts/15/../Page.aspx?Id=" + properties.ListItem.ID;
                    properties.ListItem["Link"] = urlValue;

                    properties.ListItem.Update();
                    base.ItemAdded(properties);
              }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
```